# New/ relevant ways to retrieve intraday stock pricing

Tags: pricing, intraday

I am trying my best to find cheap/ free ways to retrieve and store intraday stock prices - both historically and going forward.  Many of the ways I find seem to be outdated and no longer exist. For data going forward, I could probably create a scheduler to just spawn during the day scrape websites for this information, but I may be overlooking an easier solution. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: For which markets?

Comment: What methods have you tried that are outdated?

Comment: US Equities works for now. I recall pulling this data a couple years back using yahoo and google finance.